# Can the hardware and software tags be obliterated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Do we really need the [hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware) and [software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software) tags?

Looking at the tags into detail:

- They **don't group all the questions** that should belong to them.
- Their **statistics don't make sense**, they are both *less popular* than [command-line](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/command-line).
- They have **no additional value when searching**, as you would look for more specific things.

Looking at the questions tagged into detail:

- It's **clear from the other tags and title** if the question is about [hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware) or [software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software).
- It's **very weird** to add [software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software) next to [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) or [hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware) to [cpu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu).
- **There is no single question** that actually *needs* the tag.

To me, [hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware) and [software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software) [**are meta tags**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

Let's check:

1. **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.**

   If a question was tagged software, we have to wonder about *what software*. **Check!**

   If a question was tagged hardware, we have to wonder about *what hardware*. **Check!**
2. **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.**

   *What software* are you thinking about? Or *what hardware*? **Check!**

So, can the [hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware) and [software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software) tags be obliterated?

> The problem is that **these "meta" tags cover "all" questions on the site, while there isn't a single question that needs such a tag**. Can anyone give sufficient counter-examples? From a software engineering perspective, these tags are like [god classes](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GodClass) while they better fit to be used in the form of the [mediator pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MediatorPattern) (thus in the form of tag sets).
>
> — Source: Private discussion

— Originated from: [Area 51 - Computer Hardware Proposal Discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-does-computer-hardware-add-that-isnt-already-available-on-super-user/104#104), [Chat Discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/conversation/hardware-and-software) & Tagging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree -- these tags add nothing, and they are [perilously close to meta-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), which are forbidden. Ask yourself this:

> Could a (valid) question have the *single* tag [software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software)?
>   Could a (valid) question have the *single* tag [hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware)?

I think the answer is clearly *no* in both cases.

So, I have burninated these two tags.

[image]

Comment: **IMPORTANT COMMENT REMINDER**: you may now have some questions tagged untagged, which *only* had these tags, which need to be retagged and/or deleted if they are of no value and unanswered for long enough .. http://superuser.com/tags/untagged

Comment: Yeesh 96 questions tagged `[untagged]` - got it down to 82 for now

Comment: Now at 50 questions & I've exhausted my Mod flags for the day

Comment: **Done!** Just need a moderator to retag the last question there...

Comment: Nice job @Sathya and @TomWij!

Comment: Yes, this is the best meta answer to date!