# SU Retag Request: [computers] + [pc] --> [computer] or [pc]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Can a synonym be made for [computers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computers) and can [computer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer) and [pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pc) be merged into a single tag?

Answer (score 1):

I may have made it unnecessarily complex but I ended up suggesting [computers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computers) as a synonym of [computer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer) and then [computer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer) as a synonym of [pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pc) rather than making the first two synonyms of the third.

Unfortunately I can't "unsuggest" a synonym.

Comment: Hmm, thinking about it again, we might want [pc] in [computer] instead of [computer] in [pc] as not all computers are personal. I can't vote on the proposals. I really would have a benefit of having 10k reputation, but I'm halfway... :-(

Comment: @Tom true. Perhaps a mod can sort it out?

Comment: I've removed the [computers] to [computer] mapping and merged the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't [computer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer) a meta-tag?
And I imagine [pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pc) is perilously close to being one as well...

For the same reasons as discussed over in [Can the hardware and software tags be obliterated?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2017/can-the-hardware-and-software-tags-be-obliterated)

Surely *every* question on SU should be related to computers (as per the FAQ), and therefore every question should use this tag... looks very meta to me.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a meta tag too now...

Answer (score 0):

[computers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computers) has been obliterated as per [DMA57361's answer](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2019/su-retag-request-computers-pc-computer-or-pc/2024#2024), it clearly was a meta tag.

We still have [computer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer) and [pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pc), I think [computer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer) can be obliterated but we need to pay special attention to the questions in [pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pc) as they are **personal** and thus that tag could be used in the same way [server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/server) is used...

[explain](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/explain) has been obliterated in the same way, and [mind-mapping-software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mind-mapping-software) has also been retagged to [mind-mapping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mind-mapping) and an optional [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec).