# Shouldn't the hardware tag be enabled?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

Currently, the "Hardware" tag is disabled:

[image]

However, things such as "Hardware-failure" are allowed.

The reason the tag was closed (based on my research) is that it lead to quite a bit of shopping questions. **Shopping questions should remain unallowed** however there are plenty of valid uses for this: [Example](https://superuser.com/questions/593325/how-do-i-remove-the-glue-left-behind-by-those-intel-stickers) - Yes, the question *is* a duplicate however the best tag I could use for it was "Laptop", and that isn't a very good tag.

Again, this should **only** be used for hardware problems (not necessarily *failures*, just *problems*). The rule about no shopping would still apply.

Comment: the tag was not allowed because it's a meta tag. [Can the hardware and software tags be obliterated?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2017)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the tag was not allowed because it's a meta tag. [Can the hardware and software tags be obliterated?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2017)

> these tags add nothing, and they are perilously close to meta-tags